# Running wso2mb3.1.0 on windows fails to start

Tags: windows-7-x64, wso2-message-broker

I'm trying to start the wso2mb on windows 7 (java 1.7.0_71) and when I try to run (in local) the command:

```
wso2server.bat --run
```

I get the following error:

```
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,162] ERROR {org.wso2.andes.server.Main} -  Exception during startup. Triggering shutdown
org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesException: Unable to initialise application registry
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startupImpl(Broker.java:308)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startup(Broker.java:110)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.startBroker(Main.java:217)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.execute(Main.java:206)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.<init>(Main.java:54)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Main.main(Main.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.startAndesBroker(
QpidServiceComponent.java:391)
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.activate(QpidServ
iceComponent.java:155)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(Servi
ceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(S
erviceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(Serv
iceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(Instan
ceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(Insta
nceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:34
3)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.
java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.ser
viceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEv
ent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventM
anager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchr
onous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServ
iceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServ
iceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.reg
ister(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerSer
vice(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerSe
rvice(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerSe
rvice(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.internal.ServerAdminServiceComponent.act
ivate(ServerAdminServiceComponent.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(Servi
ceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(S
erviceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(Serv
iceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(Instan
ceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(Insta
nceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:34
3)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.
java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.ser
viceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEv
ent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventM
anager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchr
onous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServ
iceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
     at           org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServ
iceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.reg
ister(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerSer
vice(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerSe
rvice(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerSe
rvice(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(Carbon
ServerManager.java:514)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManag
er.java:219)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(Car
bonCoreServiceComponent.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(Servi
ceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(S
erviceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(Serv
iceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(Instan
ceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(Insta
nceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:34
3)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.
java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.ser
viceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEv
ent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventM
anager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchr
onous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServ
iceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServ
iceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.reg
ister(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerSer
vice(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerSe
rvice(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpServi
ce(Activator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(A
ctivator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServ
let.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationS
ervlet.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.
java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.
java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:10
87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContex
t.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5550)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.transport.TransportException: Could not bind to     /0.0.0
.0:5672
    at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport.accept(Min
aNetworkTransport.java:147)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startAMQPListener(Broker.java:201)
    at org.wso2.andes.server.Broker.startupImpl(Broker.java:295)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:
214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketAcceptor.registerNew(Socke
tAcceptor.java:363)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketAcceptor.access$800(Socket
Acceptor.java:55)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketAcceptor$Worker.run(Socket
Acceptor.java:222)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnabl
e.java:51)
    ... 1 more
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,184]  INFO     {org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ApplicationRegis
try} -  Shutting down     ApplicationRegistry(org.wso2.andes.server.registry.Configu
rationFileApplicationRegistry@517d5720)
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,189]  INFO     {org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ApplicationRegis
try} -  Shutting down   ApplicationRegistry:org.wso2.andes.server.registry.Configu
rationFileApplicationRegistry@517d5720
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,192]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.security.auth.manager.Pri
ncipalDatabaseAuthenticationManager} -  Unregistering UserManagementMBean
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,194]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
-  Shutdown hook triggered....
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,195]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
-  Gracefully shutting down WSO2 Message Broker...
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,196]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -    Starting to switch to maintenance mode...
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,197]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -      Stopped all transport listeners
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,197]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Waiting for request service completion...
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,199]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  All requests have been served.
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,199]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Waiting for deployment completion...
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,200]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -     All deployment tasks have been completed.
[2016-09-02 12:53:09,200]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -     Waiting for server task completion...
[2016-09-02 12:53:11,314]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} -  Default Embedded Solr   Server Initialized
[2016-09-02 12:53:11,315]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  All server tasks have been completed.
[2016-09-02 12:53:11,315]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
-  Shutting down WSO2 Message Broker...
[2016-09-02 12:53:11,317]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager}
-  Shutting down OSGi framework...
```

It says in http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2016-May/062810.html that it may be a configuration issue (i'm using the default settings), but i checked in  https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Broker+Nodes and the file looks correct. Also, i coppied the code for broker xml in https://github.com/wso2/puppet-modules/blob/master/modules/wso2mb/templates/3.1.0/repository/conf/broker.xml.erb#L37 but it fails to parse the xml in line 37 (<%= @mb_thrift_server %>)

The thing is i just donwloaded the wso2mq and i haven't been able to start this server, and is dissapointing that it fails only trying to start the server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check whether the pack is Unzipped properly. Completely delete the pack, Unzip the pack again and try again. It seems the pack is corrupted. Also make sure the download file is not corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the port 5672 is already been used. You can check it by issuing the below command.

```
netstat -a -n -o | find "5672"
```

If it is used by some other program you can stop it or change the amqp port located in broker.xml from 5672 to a port that is free.